# Where can I find statistics about Facebook applications?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to find a source for Facebook Application statistics.  I'm most interested in getting a comprehensive list of the applications in the system, and how many monthly active users each app has.  I know this information is available on each application's page, but aside from crawling Facebook, is this information available somewhere, or via Facebook's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Applications Leaderboard http://statistics.allfacebook.com/applications/leaderboard/

Answer (score 0):

Check facebook insights

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{urAppIdHere}/insights
```